# How to change frontend language only

Tags: language

I'm new to WP with no development skills. I've created a shop which is about to finish. We now realised that we are only going to use one language, instead of two which was the first plan.
So now, i have turned all texts etc from english to greek (which is the one we are going to use) but some things cannot edit (such as cart buttons/ checkout texts/ emails etc)

I've tried changing the Site Lang from Settings but that didn't work. How can i make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

go to /wp-admin/options-general.php

and set the language that you need, after this if you see some words that not change, install a plugin [LocoTranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) , with this you can see and edit any language of theme or plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I noticed today that some titles etc on frontend have changed to greek, since the day i changed the site language fron English to Greek, but some others have not. I'll try using the plugin you suggested and see what happens. Thanks a lot!